# Can an accusative noun with a definite article precede a dative noun with an indefinite article in the word order?

Tags: word-order

One of the object rules in word order that i have read is that ," if both the accusative and dative objects are nouns then the dative precedes the accusative". I came across an example with the following word order,

" Wir geben das Buch einem Mann "

1. How the above word order is correct when it is not as per the rule that i have mentioned?
2. If the word order is correct then what is the reason for that?
3. Is there any other acceptable word order beyond the rules for the word order wrt the objects?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is correct usage of German.

I *assume* * the rule here is: what is emphasized? 
That is why the "Mann" is at the end, because this is the important part of the message. The book had to be given someone, just whom was to point out.

*<sub>I did not even know your mentioned rule :-o</sub>

Comment: Thanks and let me see what others have to say,